# I can not locate a site error

Tags: html, css

Hello everyone I was working on a site I'm sure is right, but there is an error that makes the site does not appear its layout I'll be leaving there

Can anyone help me solve this?

[image]

Comment: no idea what it is suppose to look like, so cant help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css is is not loaded. Right click on the page  -> "inspect element"-> "console" -> check the error message there. Certainly it's the CSS not loading.

Comment: I think I found it to be 2 javascript and css errors, now I do not know how to solve it seems everything is okay

Comment: In the console there is no more error, only the layout does not appear

Comment: Paste the javascript errors here and remember to upvote the answers that helped

Comment: can you send put the url here? perhaps your css file is empty.

Comment: I posted the whole javascript because it's too big and it does not fit here

Comment: I don't think there is an error with your js, it's just a missing asset, check your css file if there's a missing curly bracket somewhere or supply the url to your website so I can check myself. :-)

Comment: on here url http://arede.pe.hu/we/menu.php

Answer (score 0):

have you inspect the code 
i think you have missing asset files i.e CSS and javascript files

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*
** jquery.cookie.js
*/

jQuery.cookie = function (key, value, options) {

    // key and value given, set cookie...
    if (arguments.length > 1 && (value === null || typeof value !== "object")) {
        options = jQuery.extend({}, options);

        if (value === null) {
            options.expires = -1;
        }

        if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
            var days = options.expires, t = options.expires = new Date();
            t.setDate(t.getDate() + days);
        }

        return (document.cookie = [
            encodeURIComponent(key), '=',
            options.raw ? String(value) : encodeURIComponent(String(value)),
            options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
            options.path ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
            options.domain ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
            options.secure ? '; secure' : ''
        ].join(''));
    }

    // key and possibly options given, get cookie...
    options = value || {};
    var result, decode = options.raw ? function (s) { return s; } : decodeURIComponent;
    return (result = new RegExp('(?:^|; )' + encodeURIComponent(key) + '=([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie)) ? decode(result[1]) : null;
};

function selecao(obj, def_texto_padrao){
    if(obj.constructor == String){obj = document.getElementById(obj);}
    var def_texto = (def_texto_padrao) ? function(text){obj.value += text;} : function(){return false;};
    var selecao = {text: "", defTexto: def_texto};
    if(document.selection){
        var faixa = document.selection.createRange();
        if(faixa.text){
            selecao.text = faixa.text;
            selecao.defTexto = function(text){
                faixa.text = text.replace(/\r?\n/g, "\r\n");
            }
    }
    } else if(typeof(obj.selectionStart) != "undefined"){
        selecao.text = obj.value.substring(obj.selectionStart, obj.selectionEnd);
        selecao.defTexto = function(text){
            obj.value = obj.value.substring(0, obj.selectionStart) + text + obj.value.substring(obj.selectionEnd);
            return false;
        }
    } else if(window.getSelection){
        selecao.text = window.getSelection().toString();
    }
    return selecao;
}
function setBBCode(obj, antes, depois){
    var selecionado = selecao(obj, false);
    selecionado.defTexto(antes + selecionado.text + depois);
    $('#'+obj).focus();
}
function setAltBBCode(obj, tipo, objthis){
    valor = objthis.value;
    var selecionado = selecao(obj, true);
    selecionado.defTexto('['+tipo+'='+valor+']' + selecionado.text + '[/'+tipo+']');
    objthis.value='';
    $('#'+obj).focus();
}

/**
* jquery.tools.min.js
```